# Salesforce Question

Tags: linux, centos

I'm running on CentOs 6.9 and I'm trying to run the Salesforce2Hadoop program found [here](https://github.com/datadudes/salesforce2hadoop). I already have the enterprise.wsdl file within the folder but I am receiving this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Desktop/Salesforce2Hadoop (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at scala.xml.Source$.fromFile(XML.scala:22)
at scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader$class.loadFile(XMLLoader.scala:50)
at scala.xml.XML$.loadFile(XML.scala:60)
at co.datadudes.wsdl2avro.WSDL2Avro$.convert(WSDL2Avro.scala:98)
at co.datadudes.sf2hadoop.SFImportCLIRunner$.handleCommand(SFImportCLIRunner.scala:48)
at co.datadudes.sf2hadoop.SFImportCLIRunner$.delayedEndpoint$co$datadudes$sf2hadoop$SFImportCLIRunner$1(SFImportCLIRunner.scala:39)
at co.datadudes.sf2hadoop.SFImportCLIRunner$delayedInit$body.apply(SFImportCLIRunner.scala:10)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
at co.datadudes.sf2hadoop.SFImportCLIRunner$.main(SFImportCLIRunner.scala:10)
at co.datadudes.sf2hadoop.SFImportCLIRunner.main(SFImportCLIRunner.scala)
```

In Terminal, I typed this:

```
    [SmallsRashad@Rashad Salesforce2Hadoop]$ java -jar sf2hadoop.jar init
    -u rashad.smalls@theremigroup.com -p ******** -b /base/path -w
    /Desktop/Salesforce2Hadoop./enterprise.wsdl -s /path/to/state-file
    Name
```

What am I doing wrong?

SN: I omitted the password for obvious reasons.

Comment: Seems like it is looking for a file at `/Desktop/Salesforce2Hadoop` and that file is not there.  Can you update your question with more information about the steps you took up to this error?

Comment: `/Desktop/Salesforce2Hadoop./enterprise.wsdl` not too sure what you are trying to achieve. howerver should that not be `/Desktop/Salesforce2Hadoop/.enterprise.wsdl`  ?

Comment: @DeclanGallagher I'm trying to run a program to import Salesforce data into Hadoop.

Comment: The path `/Desktop/Salesforce2Hadoop./enterprise.wsdl` looks wrong (a dot at the end of a directory name is unusual), but it is also inconsistent with the error message you posted, which mentions `/Desktop/Salesforce2Hadoop`, no dot. Are you sure the command you posted is actually the one you ran?